# Clearing p-autocomplete primeng after hitting enter

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

Using PrimeNG auto-complete, I have the following html.

```
<p-autoComplete
    id="autocomplete"
    [(ngModel)]="termToSearch"
    [minLength]=1
    [suggestions]="suggestedData"
    (completeMethod)="search($event)"
    placeholder="Search by name..."
    (onSelect)="goToDetailPage($event)"
    (onClear)="clearInput()"
    (keydown.enter)="onSearchSubmit($event)"
    [forceSelection]=false>
 </p-autocomplete>
```

when the user hits the 'enter' key instead of selecting one of the options in the dropdown, I have a `onSearchSubmit` function.

That function looks like this:

```
clearInput() {
    this.termToSearch = null;
  }

  clearSuggestions() {
    this.suggestedData = null;
  }

 onSearchSubmit(event) {
    this.clearSuggestions();
    this.clearInput();
    // before we do a general search for whatever was entered, hide the suggestions dropdown
    this.router.navigate(["/search/results"], {queryParams: { q: event.target.value }});
}
```

For the most part, this works, yet at the same time it doesn't. It clears the suggestion list, but it doesn't hide the entire suggestion dropdown, so the UI ends up looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Whenever need to clear the suggestion list use this

   `this.suggestedData = []`
2. To close the suggestion dropdown manually use primeNg autocomplete component **.hide()**

   `AutoComplete.hide()`

Implementation In HTML

```
<p-autoComplete
    id="autocomplete"
    #autocomplete
    [(ngModel)]="termToSearch"
    [minLength]=1
    [suggestions]="suggestedData"
    (completeMethod)="search($event)"
    placeholder="Search by name..."
    (onSelect)="goToDetailPage($event)"
    (onClear)="clearInput()"
    (keydown.enter)="autocomplete.hide();onSearchSubmit($event)"
    [forceSelection]=false>
 </p-autocomplete>
```

In its TS add
`import { AutoComplete } from 'primeng/autocomplete';`

`@ViewChild('autocomplete') autocomplete:AutoComplete;`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I have a build error. Property autocomplete doesn't exist...

Comment: Please add autocomplete as ViewChild in its TS file. Updated answer for the same.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

Comment: This should not come Check this sample StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocomplete-hide?file=src/app/app.component.html